# Javascript loop: returning 1 to 10 and then again (restarting loop)

Tags: javascript, loops, cookies

Context: I’m working with cookies based on the tutorial in [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). The idea is to set up to 10 cookies given by the search queries entered by the user (that is, only the last 10 entries should be stored).

I have a function that generates a name for each of the 10 cookies (“Search_Entry”+i). It all works fine until the 11th entry, where I would like the function to again return the first possible name and then the second, third, etc., so in that way the value already stored under those names would simply be replaced by the new one. In a way I want the loop to somehow restart, although that doesn’t seem to be a simple option.

```
var g_iMaxSearchQueries = 10;
function dynamicCookieName() {
    var l_aCurrentCookie;
    for (var i = 0; i < g_iMaxSearchQueries; i++) {
        l_aCurrentCookie = getCookie("Search_Entry"+i);
        if(l_aCurrentCookie == "" && i < g_iMaxSearchQueries) {
            return "Search_Entry"+i;
        } else if (i == 9) { //this “else” needs to be an “else if” in order for the condition to work properly. Maybe is (i == 9) not the right one but the only one that worked for me from what I’ve tried.  
        //here would the loop start running again exactly like in the first part.
        }
    }
}
```

I have searched everywhere, to my best knowledge, and tried several different things, also more complex potential solutions but the basic problem is still the same, that’s why my question and the version of the code I posted refers to the core of what I need. Maybe someone with more knowledge and experience can throw some light on this. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `i%g_iMaxSearchQueries`?

Comment: `&& i < g_iMaxSearchQueries` is redundant in the current for loop

Comment: @depperm Thanks for your comments but I'm not sure what you have in mind with your suggestion (i%g_iMaxSearchQueries).

Comment: your current function (to me not seeing the context) doesn't make sense. But `i%g_iMaxSearchQueries` will make sure that you never go over the max cookies. If `i` is 12 will result in 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g_currCookie%g_iMaxSearchQueries` will ensure that your cookie key name doesn't go past 9.

Here is a small example of adding up to 10 cookies:

```
var my_search = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen']

var g_currCookie = 0;
var g_iMaxSearchQueries = 10;

function addCookie() {
  document.cookie = "Search_Entry" + (g_currCookie%g_iMaxSearchQueries) + "=" + my_search[g_currCookie%my_search.length];
  g_currCookie++;
}

function getCookies() {
  console.log(document.cookie);
}

function resetCookies() {
  for (var i = 0; i < g_iMaxSearchQueries; i++) {
    document.cookie = "Search_Entry" + i + '=;';
  }
}
//From https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
function getCookie(num) {
  var name = Search_Entry + num + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qbk0Lvpa/)

Comment: Thanks! It seems to do what I want. I just need to see if I can adapt it to my project as it is. I tried to vote your answer as useful but my votes don't really count yet...

Comment: Hi there! Your code does the trick regarding my original question. The problem is though, that, since in my project the array is generated dynamically with the users search queries, it gets lost every time the page reloads (that is, everytime the search button is clicked) and that results in only the first saved cookie being rewritten. I haven't been able to find a solution to this and that's why I'm wondering if you or someone else might have a suggestion in this regard. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the loop to execute continuously, 
  the condition `i++` can be changed to

```
i = (i + 1)%g_iMaxSearchQueries
```

or
in the else if part, set i back to 0.

```
else if(i==9) {
    i = 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to be working for me.